# How to import CSV file into an attached database?

Tags: sqlite, csv, import

I am trying to import a CSV file into an attached database. Primary database is X.db, E.db is attached to it and contains table `E_table`.

I tried :

```
.mode csv
.import C:/1/05112022.CSV E.E_table
```

There are no error messages but CSV is not inserted into `E_Table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `--schema` option to the `.import` command, like so:

```
.import --schema E C:/1/05112022.CSV E_table
```

Note that you specify the attached schema in the option, and do NOT qualify the table name with the schema.

The docs for this option are [here](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#importing_files_as_csv_or_other_formats)

Note that the `--schema` option requires SQLite version 3.38.0 or higher.